# How to group the same elements in an ArrayList and get the number of each unique element?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
 String[] product=req.getParameterValues("product");
 String[] amount = req.getParameterValues("amount");
```

Now I have two parameters passing from JSP to Servlet. The number of product and the number of amount are not fixed but they are the same. Each amount[i] is referred to a product[i]. However, there might be some elements in the product[] have the same value. I want to group elements with the same value together and get a new Arraylist of product and amount. What should I do?

Comment: Create a `Map<String, ?>` where you map the product names to (sum of) amounts.

Comment: Actually I have two things to do. First, I need to find product elements with the same value and group them. Second, I need to get the quantity of each product group. For example, we have product={"Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple"}, amount={2, 3, 3, 2}. Then after grouping, they should be product={"Apple", "Pear", "Banana"}, amount={4, 3, 3}

Comment: `final String product = products[i]; final Integer amount = Integer.valueOf(amounts[i]); if (map.contains(product)) { map.put(map.get(product) + amount ; } else { map.put(amount); }`

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Map as suggested by someone in comments section. See a working example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String []args){
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        String[] products = {"Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple"};
        String[] amounts = {"2", "3", "3", "2"};

        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            String product = products[i];
            int amount = Integer.valueOf(amounts[i]);

            if (myMap.containsKey(product)) {
                myMap.put(product, myMap.get(product) + amount);
            } else {
                myMap.put(product, amount);
            }
        }

        for (String product : myMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(product + ": " + myMap.get(product));
        }
     }
}
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html